# Lambda function in pyspark not working with python code

Tags: apache-spark, machine-learning, pyspark, data-science, apache-spark-sql

I have written code in python, which I am trying to move to PySpark but facing syntax issue. can someone review my below Python code and assist to get the same output in `pySpark`.

```py
data_pit['Was_or_is_Active_Curr_FY'] = data_pit['Termination_Date'].apply(\
    lambda x: 'Y' if pd.isnull(x) or x > datetime.date(2017, 4, 1) else 'N')

data_pit = data_pit[(data_pit['Was_or_is_Active_Curr_FY']=='Y')]
data_pit.drop(columns=['Was_or_is_Active_Curr_FY'], inplace=True)
```

Here `data_pit` is a table and `'Termination_date'` is a column.

I have tried below code:-

```
data_pit['Was_or_is_Active_Curr_FY']=data_pit.map(lambda x:'Y' if col.("Termination_Date")isNull or col.("Termination_Date") > datetime(2017, 4, 1) else 'N' )
```

I got bellow error from my code:-

```
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
  File "<command-10442673922623>", line 1
    data_pit['Was_or_is_Active_Curr_FY']=data_pit.map(lambda x:'Y' if col.("Termination_Date")isNull or col.("Termination_Date") > datetime(2017, 4, 1) else 'N' )
                                                                          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Your prompt response will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Hello. It would be helpful if you could provide the error logs, if any. If no syntax error, then some sample input output would help.

Comment: Hello there, I have updated my code with error with Syntax error.

Comment: Didn't you just misplaced the dots? It should be something like: `col("Termination_Date").isNull`.... 
But I also ask myself why do you need map at all? you just want to create a new column based on some conditions or? I will post an answer, which should do the work

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion your problem does not require `map` at all. If you just want to create a new column `Was_or_is_Active_Curr_FY` and identify whether the termination date is set and if it is greater than some other date you can use `withColumn`

```python
data_pit.withColumn("Was_or_is_Active_Curr_FY", when((col("Termination_Date").isNull()) | (col("Termination_Date") >  datetime.date(2017, 4, 1)), "Y").otherwise("N"))
```

I have a small example that uses different data but does similar things. It adds a column with `"Y"` and `"N"` based on the fact whether `col1` fulfills 2 conditions.

```python
test_df = spark.createDataFrame([
    (1,"2"),(3,"4"),(10,"11"),              
    ], ("col1","col2"))

test_df.withColumn("your_result", when((col("col1")==1) | (col("col1")==3), "Y").otherwise("N")).show()

#+----+----+-----------+
#|col1|col2|your_result|
#+----+----+-----------+
#|   1|   2|          Y|
#|   3|   4|          Y|
#|  10|  11|          N|
#+----+----+-----------+
```